# package.json Для виндовс 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Нужен package.json где можна скачать либо установить?Нужен для Gulp из-за него не хочет устанавливаться.Спасибо вам большое заранее!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполните команду `npm init` введите необходимые параметры, такие как имя, версия, описание.

Подробней здесь.
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init

По скриншоту не совсем понятно. Вы пытаетесь установить `gulp` или выполнить `task` под название `install` .

Если установить тогда `npm install gulp -S`

Comment: Спасибо.Сейчас попробую я пытаюсь установить package.json

Comment: Ввожу имя файла все нормально перехожу на версию не могу ничего ввести.Как будто клавиатура отключена.Имею ввиду npm init

Comment: Можешь не вводить версию, просто нажав enter по умолчанию будет 1.0.0  . Потом в package.json поменяешь, или же, напиши нужную версию где-то, скопирую ее, и потом в консоли через ПКМ вставь ее.